# What may be the reason for Django sudden static files load failure?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I have successfully deployed my first Django project(though still working on the addition of other functionalities) http://167.172.62.187 now back to the development machine I wanted to strengthen my understanding of Django by developing an eCommerce app. No error was shown, static files were collected successfully, loaded static files in the frontend but static files didn't work when I tested my app in my localhost. Another strange issue I noticed was that even my blog that's working perfectly before stopped rendering static files too. I set debug=True in both cases and I am using one virtual environment for my Django applications. Please I am confused and I need your help.

Comment: show your settings.py static settings

Comment: What do you mean static files were collected successfully, under debug mode, static files are collected automatically, when `runserver` is run. You could probably check that your templates have `{% load static %}` see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete cookies and cache.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot, cookies and cache was the problem.

Comment: No worries! Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped :)